# В шаблоне Thymeleaf поле помеченное disabled возвращает null

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Переделываю шаблон с JSP на Thymeleaf и столкнулся с непонятным поведением.

Логика работы страницы следующая: загружается страница с формой заранее заполненной некоторыми значениями, все поля доступны для редактирования кроме поля ID. Это поле отмечено как Disabled:

В JSP все отрабатывает как надо - форма отображается со значениями, поле ID при этом серого цвета и не доступно для редактирования. При отправке методом POST все данные включая ID улетают на сервер.

В JSP поле с ID выглядит так:

```
<form:input path="id" size="8" disabled="true"/>
```

Когда делаю тоже самое средствами Thymeleaf, то отображается на странице все корректно, т.е. в поле ID записано значение, само поле серого цвета и его нельзя редактировать, но при отправке на сервер ID приходит со значением 0.

В Thymeleaf поле с ID выглядит так:

```
<input id=bookId type="text"  th:field="*{id}" th:disabled="true"/>
```

Пока проверял в чем дело, выяснил, что любое поле, как только его помечаешь disabled приводит к  тому, что отправляется либо 0 либо null, если поле текстовое.

Как в Thymeleaf сделать поле недоступным и при этом, чтобы нормально отправлялось? Под недоступным я имею ввиду не readonly а именно сделать неактивным поле как элемент управления.

Answer (score 1):

Это [стандартное поведение](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set) html-форм, поля с атрибутом `disabled` не отправляются. Так что если JSP и берёт откуда-то ID, то точно не из запроса.